# How to split a string to different csv fields with Perl?

Tags: csv, perl

I have a string like this :

```
$string = '2020/3/12;SHDXIALI2; 2020 R2 (build 20200310T205904);TCA-SC-PerfDV-0030;DesignVerifier_Perf.etp;11;6;90'
```

I want to save each field to csv column like this (display of how it would look like when opened in Excel rather than the real file):

```
2020/3/12 SHDXIALI2 2020 R2 (build 20200310T205904) TCA-SC-PerfDV-0030 DesignVerifier_Perf.etp 11 6 90
```

[image: opened in Excel]

How could I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the string from and how? Having an array would be much better.

Comment: Also, what you show is an Excel screenshot, not a CSV. Please, update your question with a real CSV pasted as text instead of a picture.

Comment: @choroba Hi ,The string is I split the array~ Because I want to write the data information to the .csv file format,and there are nine Fields and I want to store in the .csv file displayed nine coulmns.But I don't know why it just displayed in one row and just in the one cell~

Comment: @Xiali - substitute each `;` to `,` and store it in a file.

Comment: so all you're doing is translating `;` to a single whitespace?

Comment: This question is confused. But, I'm supposing you want to transform this `2020/3/12;SHDXIALI2; 2020 R2 (build 20200310T205904);TCA-SC-PerfDV-0030;DesignVerifier_Perf.etp;11;6;90` to a CSV format. In this case, you must to replace ';' to ','. However is common people using ';' as a separator in CSV files. So, theoreticaly there is no problem to use data with ';' as a separator instead ','.

Comment: It depends on Excel version but the one you are using splits csv automatically by recognizing ',' and not ';' . You could change the string that each field will be separated by commas like this: `$string =~ s/;/,/g;`

Comment: @zubenel Thanks for your answer. Now It's ok. I implement the function I want to do ~

Comment: @AndreCarneiro Thanks for your answer !

Comment: @PolarBear Yes , you are right ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that CSV in most systems should use `,` as a separator (and not `;`, although this separator is used for example in France).

Therefore, the following could would work well:

```
open (fh,"+>>", "C:/test.csv") || die "test.csv 文件无法打开, $!";
$string ="2020/3/12,SHDXIALI2,2020 R2 (build 20200310T205904),TCA-SC-PerfDV-0030,DesignVerifier_Perf.etp,11,6,90";
print fh "$string\n";
close fh;
```

And if you HAVE to start from the string you mention in your question, then you need to do some replacement

```
$string =~ s/;/,/g;
```